# Merging and combining columns and rows in r

Tags: r

I have two data sets with many columns called the same and others differently, about 350 columns. How I can combine all this data?

[combination of df1 and df2 to create df3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLMMV.png)

Comment: I have about 350 columns, can not do that manually!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `bind_rows` in this case:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

```
     x1    x2 x3     x4   
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>
1    10    40 male   NA   
2    20    50 male   NA   
3    30    60 female NA   
4    50    NA female b    
5    40    NA male   a    
6    30    NA female c
```

data

```
df1 <- tribble(
  ~x1, ~x2, ~x3,
  10, 40, "male",
  20, 50, "male",
  30, 60, "female"
)

df2 <- tribble(
  ~x1, ~x3, ~x4,
  50, "female", "b",
  40, "male", "a", 
  30, "female", "c"
)
```